# Is there any other function of DNA?

Tags: genetics, dna

We all know that DNA acts as a genetic molecule. Does DNA have any other function in the cell other than being a genetic material and carrier of information?

Answer (score 10):

In [eukaryotes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eukaryote) DNA has a structural as well coding function. Parts of chromosomes called [centromeres](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centromere) bind to proteins and form a scaffold which helps chromosomes attach to each other and correctly segregate during division. Technically this is still related to the transmission of genetic information though.

Since RNA can act as an enzyme (the so-called [ribozymes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribozyme)), scientists have hypothesized that DNA can also have an enzymatic function, but no such function has been found in nature. Artificial DNA enzymes (deoxiribozymes) have been designed to cleave DNA, covalently modify proteins, ligate RNA molecules, and even catalyze reactions between small molecules. [See this lab's website.](http://www.scs.illinois.edu/silverman/research/index.html)

Comment: as far as i know DNAzymes are purely synthetic.. Are there natural DNAzymes too ??

Comment: No, there are only synthetic ones

Comment: I want any other function inside living cells. Is there any ?

Comment: From what I researched, no

Answer (score 3):

DNA has the following functions other than genetic material :

1. It can function as a molecule that attaches to TLR ( Toll like Receptor ) on or in cells and so  can contribute to innate immune response.
2. It can act as carbon source. ( We have nucleases enzymes in our intestines.)
3. It can be structural component of biofilms.
4. It can also influence pH in cells as it is an acid.
5. It is a structural component of neutrophil extracellular traps to wrap up microbes.

Please feel free to correct any errors I have made.

Answer (score 1):

DNA has been shown to be important for biofilm formation in certain bacteria.  This is extracellular DNA that comes from cell lysis.

Comment: Interesting! Can you give a reference?

Comment: Heres the first one I could find that is open source, but if you search "extracellular DNA biofilm" in google theres loads of papers on it: http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0016861

Answer (score -1):

Yes, maintenance of the genome.  But not DNA specifically, but DNA and all of its associated proteins.

Comment: Could you give a bit more detail here? It's hard to tell what you're referring to.